# Scale and snapping ... something doesn't work

Tags: transforms, snapping, scale

I have a problem with snap and scale. I follow the tutorial on this forum.

[image]
but it doesn't work for me because when I try to achieve the border that I want to reach, my object goes on another direction and continues to scale. why the object behave in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The maneuver in your illustration is a constrained scale along global X, with the 3D cursor as pivot.  I'm not sure how the constraint was applied; I would expect to see it in the keystrokes or in the use of X axis of the scale manipulator.

Anyway, the settings show: "snap the 'Closest' element (vertex) of your transforming  selection to a 'vertex' on the target, (chosen by hovering over it), while transforming the rest of the selection with it"

So the moves are:

1. Ensure the pivot is at the center of your scale. That's the point which won't move
2. Select the vertices you want scaled away from the pivot
3. Hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, or use the manipulator to constrain the scale to X
4. Hover over the target vertex
5. Left-click with your cursor inside the little snap target circle to confirm.

'Closest' seems to select the vertex of the transforming selection that was closest to the hover target along the constraint axis *before the transform began* as the point to lock on the the target. At least, it does when the entire transforming selection was to one side of the target down that axis before the move was made. However I have to say I find its behavior unpredictable when the target is between or inside the source selection.

So I would much rather take the little extra time to use 'Active' as the source element. Then, in vertex mode, you know exactly which vertex will be aligned with your target by ensuring it is the last selected. That may involve <kbd>shift</kbd> right-clicking it twice.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2.93 when using the active method it seems to snap to the active one but for some reason it halts a bit before it. (Scale is applied)

Comment: Yeah this is very buggy, when using only one axis to scale it works but when doing a normal scale it totally flips out

Answer (score 0):

While you scale your object, your arrow has to touch the angle vertice of the object on which you want to snap